# Changing Conditional Format Priority in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting, schedule

I have a schedule with a collection of conditional formatting, which will be used by multiple users, most of whom are not tech-savvy. It would be easiest to allow them to drag schedule boxes around and to cut & paste, which does not work well with conditional formatting. I realize that one solution is to tell them to only copy & paste, but I'm trying to create something more robust than that.

My intended solution is to place a button on the page that just resets the conditional formatting to a template on another sheet within the same workbook. After a schedule change is made, the button would be pressed:

```
function passConditionalFormat(sourceSheetName, targetSheetName) {
      //Check what spreadsheet we're using
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
      //The source of data formatting rules
      var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Safety Sheet");
  
  //(start row, start column, #of rows to grab, #of columns to grab)
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(4, 2, 25, 8);
  
      //The target sheet of data formatting rules
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("test sheet");
      //Set target range
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange("B4:I28");
  
      //clear formatting in target sheet area
      targetRange.clearFormat();
      
      //(column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)
      sourceRange.copyFormatToRange(targetSheet, 2, 9, 4, 28);
  
    }
```

However, I have found that when I clear the former formatting and then insert the template formatting that the conditional formatting is prioritized differently, which causes me some issues. I *did* notice that the new prioritization happens to be the order in which I applied the conditional formats, so I might just delete them and write them in a different order...

[This is a screenshot before running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s5WS.png)

[This is a screenshot after running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP0cV.png)

I'm looking for a way to use Google Apps Script to modify the conditional formatting priority, which can be changed manually by dragging one above another within the list. Any help on this would be very, very appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the spreadsheet you are using to run the script? Your example screenshot is odd, the ranges are also changed. It works as intended on my side with an empty worksheet.

Comment: Edited the post to include a link. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Your answer is not correct, the behavior you are reporting is not reproducible. Have you tried using your script in a brand new sheet? Try as well deleting the whole formatting from test sheet before running your script.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'reproducible' in this context.

Comment: Reapplying the conditional formats in the template sheet in the order that they are prioritized is something that someone else can reproduce within their own sheet. If they come up with a different result, I would be happy to see it. 
The code itself already clears formatting from the applied range on the test sheet before applying the new formatting. 
The problem assumes that the formatting of the test sheet will be screwed up by other users, and so starting with a clean test sheet will not be sufficient.

Comment: This behavior: "the first created cond. format will have the highest priority". Doesn't apply to other sheets. In fact, their order is preserved when a copy is made. If you delete the conditional formatting and then use your script the order will be preserved. What I'm saying is that the reason for the ordering issue you are facing must be different than the one you put in your answer.

Comment: I see your point. My 'solution' achieves the objective I had, but does not wholly address the problem that I faced in a previous solution attempt. You have more experience on Stack Overflow than I do  - I still want to share my workaround 'solution' if anyone else can benefit from it, but I don't want to imply that the other issue I had was entirely resolved. Advice?

Comment: Provide a complete answer with your case analysed and evidences on how this behavior is reproducible. I cannot build an evidence for this behavior: copying a re-ordered conditional formatting will preserve their order, no matter what order the rules were created.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, App Scripts does not have a way to access the priorities of conditional formats.

Alessandro maintains that `copyFormatToRange` will copy the priority of the formats along with the conditional formats themselves. While I cannot outright reject this hypothesis, I can state that, in my case, the priorities of conditional formats were changed, and I do not know of another cause.

The following is a way to achieve my particular goals, though it's not as robust as I would like.
It seems that `copyFormatToRange` applies conditional formats to the new range in the order that they were originally created: the first created cond. format will have the highest priority.
So I ended up re-applying the conditional formats I was looking for in the template sheet, but in the order I'm looking for.